# Azure HTTP Function works localy but not on azure / Azure URL gives result website cant be found

Tags: python, azure, function, http

I'am working on Azure HTTP function, what I'am trying to achieve is:
Azure function based on python after calling via URL it shall connect to Linux VPS execute command and return the response from VPS.
It does exactly that after running it on localhost via Visual Studio code
[image: Example of running it]

Then exactly same code is uploaded via Azure Pipeline which runs without issues
However after calling function via Azure URL it gives 404 error.
Function IS enabled and Code is uploaded sucessfully and can be seen in 'Code + Test' section

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

import sys
import paramiko

def execute_command_on_remote_machine(ip_addr, command):
    try:
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        client.connect(str(ip_addr), username='username', password='password')
        chan = client.get_transport().open_session()
        #chan.get_pty()

        stdout = [], [], []
        stdout = client.exec_command(command, get_pty=True)

        #err_list = [line for line in stderr.read().splitlines()]
        out_list = [line for line in stdout.read().splitlines()]

        client.close()
        return out_list

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        sys.exit(1)




def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    output = execute_command_on_remote_machine("IP", "sh /home/script.sh")
    logging.info(str(output))
    return func.HttpResponse(str(output))
```

Comment: Can you cross check the URL is correct?

Comment: @Ricky G I copy link directly from Azure so its for sure correct